# Simple form format a time field to show '21:30' instead of entire UTC time string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, time, format, simple-form

My rails `_form` code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @admin_event, :html => { :class => 'main-form' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :time_of_event, :format => l(:time_of_event, '%d %b. %Y'), :as => :string, :label => 'Hora', :input_html => { :class => 'thin', :placeholder => 'eg: 20:30' } %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
Cannot convert symbol to string.
```

---

How can I set up this `_form` to always display this field using a time converter so while the database has a full field (`2000-01-01 19:30:00.000000`), in the forms it would only show `19:30`?

Answer (score 7):

Solved this with the following: created the method "time_format" on my ApplicationHelper:

```
def time_format(datetime)
  datetime.strftime('%H:%M') unless datetime.blank?
end
```

And then on the form:

```
<%= f.input_field :start_time, :as => :string, :value => time_format(f.object.start_time) %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add attr_accessor to your model (for example formatted_time) and use this field for get fromatted time and set it. Before save you can parse value of @formatted_time and apply it to time_of_event field.