# Why is the time field in a Rails 4 form showing seconds and microseconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, forms, time

I have a model with a datetime attribute.

The form to create a new model separates this attribute into a date and a time field, which the controller glues together afterwards.

On Chrome this works fine, and when I go to make a new model (the controller loads the 'new' form using a new object that has a DateTime.current attribute), the time comes up in the form field as as '09:00' as intended. However, on Safari and Firefox I get '09:00:00.000', which breaks my tests and looks odd.

How can I make the time inputs load with HH:mm instead of HH:mm:ss:mmm when a time field is loading a datetime object as its data?

Comment: Please check the answer for a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057869/simple-form-format-a-time-field-to-show-2130-instead-of-entire-utc-time-strin

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strftime` with format string `'%H:%M'`

`DateTime.current.strftime('%H:%M')`